# jqGrid: how to show the add/edit icons bottom of the grid

Tags: css, jqgrid

I am completely new to jqGrid and simply having a hard time get started as every post seem to be very advanced. I simply have a simple grid setup and now want to add the 'add/edit' icons. I have below code but they still don't show up. What else is missing?

```
$("#tabPeopleList").jqGrid('navGrid', '#tabPagerBar', { 
                                   edit: true,  <-- isn't this all there is needed?
                                   add: true,
                                   del: true,
                                   search: true,
                                   searchtext: "Search",
                                   addtext: "Add",
                                   edittext: "Edit",
                                   deltext:"Delete"
                                                            });
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? The HTML and JS please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good, just ensure that you have the following elements in your html:

```
        <table id="tabPeopleList" ></table>
        <div id="tabPagerBar"></div>
```

and in your jqGrid ititialization:

```
        pager: $('#tabPagerBar'),
```